# How to pull unique values from unsubscribe data view when there are duplicates?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, subscriber, data-views, unsubscribe

Currently, we are pulling the data from data view _unsubscribe with this approach (where primary key is concatenation of all fields).

The reason we need a primary key is to avoid adding duplicate data. Just appending creates a risk of bringing duplicate data and limiting the query to run for one day only creates a risk of losing data (if for any reason query fails to run, we will start losing the data).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
AccountID,
OYBAccountID,
JobID,
ListID,
BatchID,
SubscriberID,
SubscriberKey,
EventDate,
IsUnique,
Domain,
CONCAT(
AccountID,
OYBAccountID,
JobID,
ListID,
BatchID,
SubscriberID,
SubscriberKey,
EventDate,
IsUnique,
Domain
) as Primary_Key
FROM _Unsubscribe
Where OYBAccountID = 123456
```

**Getting an error:**
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key.

We looked into the data and found out that there are some duplicate instances.

| AccountID | OYBAccountID | JobID | ListID | BatchID | SubscriberID | SubscriberKey | Event Date | IsUnique | Domain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 202020 | 300001 | 7890 | 212 | 456789 | 67676767 | Monday, Jan 1, 2024 1:01pm | TRUE | gmail.com |
| 123456 | 202020 | 300001 | 7890 | 212 | 456789 | 67676767 | Monday, Jan 1, 2024 1:01pm | FALSE | gmail.com |
| 123456 | 202020 | 300001 | 7890 | 212 | 456789 | 67676767 | Monday, Jan 1, 2024 1:01pm | FALSE | gmail.com |

**Questions:**

1. How come there are one true record and two false records all together with exact same time?
2. How we can avoid this error and continue consuming the data without any issues?